# Application of the Clark-Ocone's Formula to $\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, malliavin-calculus

At page 291 of [Nonlinear Option Pricing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466570334) by Julien Guyon and Pierre Henry-Labordère,  the Clark-Ocone's Formula is applied to $\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}$.

I do not get how to get from the second to the third step of the following:

$$ \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t} }[(r_t-r_t^0)\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}]= $$
$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t} }\bigg[\bigg(\int_0^t\sigma_r^t(s)dB_s^t \bigg)\cdot\bigg(\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}[\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}] + \int_0^t\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}_s[D_s^{B^t}\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}]dB_s^t  + \int_0^t\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}_s[D_s^{Z^t}\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}]dZ_s^t \bigg) \bigg]=   $$

$$ \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t} }\bigg[\bigg(\int_0^t\sigma_r^t(s)dB_s^t \bigg)\cdot\bigg( \int_0^t\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}_s[D_s^{B^t}\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}]dB_s^t  \bigg) \bigg]$$

I tried to use the Malliavin integration by parts formula and to manipulate the second integral $\int_0^t\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}_s[D_s^{Z^t}\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}]dZ_s^t $ but did not manage to get to the third step.

Is it the case that: $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}[\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}] = -\int_0^t\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}_s[D_s^{Z^t}\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}]dZ_s^t $ and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the right argument, the real reason why you can get the third line is because first $B$ and $Z$ are orthogonal 
so that 
$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t} }\bigg[\bigg(\int_0^t\sigma_r^t(s)dB_s^t \bigg)\cdot\bigg(\int_0^t\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}_s[D_s^{Z^t}\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}]dZ_s^t \bigg)\bigg] =0$$
and because :
$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t} }\bigg[\bigg(\int_0^t\sigma_r^t(s)dB_s^t \bigg)\cdot\bigg(\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}[\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}]\bigg)\bigg]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t} }\bigg[\int_0^t\sigma_r^t(s)dB_s^t \bigg]\cdot\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}^{t}}\bigg[\mathbb{1}_{S_t > K}\bigg] $$ 
and on the right hand side the first term is null because $\int_0^t\sigma_r^t(s)dB_s^t$ is a martingale.

Best regards

Comment: I own you more than a beer

Comment: a minor detail: when the Brownian motion $W$ is splitted in $Z$ and $B$, where do the shouldn't a correlation coefficient come out?

Comment: @ mastro : You use Clark-Ocone's formula you don't have to use the correlation between B and W. Best regards.

Comment: but in the book it is said 'where we have expressed the Qt-Brownian motion Wt that drives the spot dynamics in terms of the (possibly multi-dimensional) Qt-Brownian motion Bt that drives the short rate dynamics and another Qt-Brownian motion Zt orthogonal to Bt'. 
So I do not get how formally Wt is splitted.

Comment: @ mastro : well $dW=\rho.dB + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}dZ$ but we don't need this, as the clark-ocone formula is applied directly on Z and B. Best regards